# export default grammar Babel ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, commonjs

Using Babel, I'm having trouble importing the following module:

```
// mongoose_helpers.js

const r_string = {
  type: String,
  required: true
}

const r_number = {
  type: Number,
  required: true
}

export default { r_string, r_number }
```

this way:

```
import { r_string, r_number } from './mongoose_helpers'
```

Which throws an error in the file I'm importing.

However it works if I do this:

```
const r_string = {
  type: String,
  required: true
}

(...)

const helpers = { r_string, r_number }

export default helpers
```

and then

```
import helpers from './mongoose_helpers'
```

Just curious what is wrong with the first approach ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`export default { r_string, r_number }` is basically exporting an object with two keys (r_string, r_number)

it will work with `import helpers from './mongoose_helpers'`

When you say `import { r_string, r_number } from './mongoose_helpers'` you are telling JS that you want two **named exports** from your modules. This is not a destructuring syntax. In order to use this, you need to specify the exports like this

```
export const r_string = ...
export const r_number = ...
```

The ultimate article on ES6 modules: http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html